# GraphicsMagick convert GIMP .xcf file to JPG

Tags: graphicsmagick

GraphicksMagick supports reading XCF files: http://www.graphicsmagick.org/formats.html

However, when I try to convert an XCF to JPG, I get the following error:

```
$ gm convert 00000680002.xcf -resize 2010 -unsharp 1+0.2+0.1 -background white -gravity center -extent 2100x2100 00000680002.jpg

gm convert: Request did not return an image.
```

If possible, I'd like to stay with GraphicsMagick because I'm also using GM to resize, sharpen, and modify the image in addition to converting it to a JPG.

How can I convert an XCF to JPG?

Comment: Try `gm identify -version` to check you have support for `xcf` installed locally.

Comment: @MarkSetchell would `XCF` be listed under "Feature Support"?